# when extending an interface, what does placing the extends declaration between <> brackets do?

Tags: java, generics, comparable

here are two examples of declaring a class:

```
public class PriorityQueue<E extends Comparable<E>>  {
//implements Comparable<E>
private ListNode front;
etc...}
```

and

```
public class PriorityQueue<E> extends Comparable<E>{ 

public PriorityQueue() {
    front = null;

etc...}
```

I know that a Class cannot extend an Interface, so the second block of code gives the error:

Comparable cannot be the superclass of PriorityQueue, a superclass must be a class

The first declaration does not give this error, only letting me know that I need to implement the compareTo method.

What does placing the extends between <> brackets do?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: It would be beneficial to the poster as well as the readers if you posted the link to the question already answered.

Comment: Link is right above the question, in case you missed it :)

Comment: Thank u. I did miss it. 1st time Using phone to look for things.

Answer (score 0):

This `<E extends Comparable<E>>` simply means that you want E to implements (or extends) `Comparable<E>`: this simply enforce the type of E to be restrained within certain bounds.